# Why doesn't my post meet quality standards?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, quality

I am trying to post this question, but it gets rejected as not meeting quality standards. What can I do to fix it?

> I have a django application runnin using django cms. I am trying to
>   make one specific submenu not clickable.
>
> The menu is like this:
>
> ```
> item1|item2|item3
>             sub_item3
>             sub_item3
> ```
>
> What i want is that everything is clickable except for "item3" menu
>   item .
>
> How can i achieve this knowing item3 is a django-cms page itself as
>   are each of its children pages ?

Comment: Note - the quality check is also applied to the title. Does the title you're entering look like a well formed sentence? If not, that's probably what's getting you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have some small grammar problems, but your question is likely not to be well-received for content problems.  One reason our filter is so strict is that grammar problems tend to correlate with content problems.  I think your question is much higher quality than many caught by this filter, but please mind the following:

1. You did not post your title, that may be the problem.  Make sure the title is a specific question that describes what you're actually trying to do.  Something like "Help with Django" is a bad title.
2. You're likely to get smacked with a bunch of [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) type comments.  You need to describe what you tried or thought to try, and what problem you had trying to get it to work.  Your question is good in that it's specific (I'm assuming this can't be found elsewhere on the site) but you are missing this ingredient.

That being said, the grammar problems that may trip this filter include capitalizing "i" and not having unnecessary spaces before punctuation , like this .  But please understand the reason our filters are meticulous is they are *indicative* of underlying content problems so much as egregious problems in themselves.

Comment: You can also [edit] and undelete posts instead of deleting one and posting another.

Comment: @slhck I know, but I felt this was very different in content and it would be disingenuous to import the vote count.  In fact I'm nearly reversing my previous answer which just instructed on the grammar/title improvements to make.

Comment: Although, my username still starts with "dj" despite my unfamiliarity with Django. That hasn't changed between answers.